# Using $timeout to for a delay

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to simulate a delay so on an Angular controller function I have:

```
vm.signup = function (model) {
  vm.mode: "busy";
  var x = true;
  $timeout(function () { x = false; }, 4000);
  vm.mode: "success";
};
```

I don't get a delay of 4 seconds between mode being set to busy and being set to success. What am I missing?

Comment: Think it should be: $timeout(function () { x = false; vm.mode: "success"; }, 4000);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$timeout` is an Asynchronous performance. And the delay occurs to everything inside the delay block.

Therefore the order of operations goes:

1. `vm.mode = busy;`
2. `var x = true;`
3. Delay starts async
4. `vm.mode = "success";`
5. Delay resolves after time: `x = false;`

I think you are wanting to have `vm.mode = 'success'` inside your timeout function:

```
vm.signup = function (model) {
  vm.mode = "busy";
  var x = true;
  $timeout(function () { 
    x = false; 
    vm.mode = "success";
  }, 4000);

};
```

Comment: Yes, that is right. I completely missed that. Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

$timeout calls whatever function is passed in after the specified delay. You need to put `vm.mode = "success"` within the function passed to $timeout.

It is **not** similar to sleep() like functions in C# and such where the entire thread is paused.